# Attach UIView to LottieFiles View

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, lottie

I've been trying to add LottieFiles animation to my new project.
I've created animation successfully but I have a problem about replacement.
I'll describe with screenshots.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoGCI.png)

As you see, I've created UIView for my animation in Interface Builder and I created some constraint.

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqrOC.png)

Problem is here, I've already set location for UIView but when I set .frame(CGRect) for my animationView It looks weird.

Here is my code;

```
let animationView = AnimationView()
@IBOutlet var weatherAnimationView: UIView!
func startAnimation() {
    animationView.animation = Animation.named("cloudy")
    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 175)
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    animationView.loopMode = .loop
    animationView.play()
    view.addSubview(animationView)
}
```

Comment: What’s your expected view structure?  Do you want to add the animationView to view or the weatherAnimationView?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in the second screenshot you created an orange view and it’s named weatherAnimationView and that it’s meant to hold the Lottie animation.

So you probably need to change

```
view.addSubview(animationView)
```

to

```
weatherAnimationView.addSubview(animationView)
```